# Code first migration error "Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed"

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I changed the data type of a field in my model from string to byte array and I got this error when I run `Update-Database` code first migration method.

> Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar(max) to varbinary(max) is
>   not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

What is the solution?

thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

SQL Server can't directly change a string to a binary, so its asking that you convert the data. With respect to Code First Migrations, I would drop the AlterColumn statements from the DbMigration, and instead manually write:

```
AddColumn("dbo.TableName", "ColumnNameTmp", c => c.Binary());
Sql("Update dbo.TableName SET ColumnNameTmp = Convert(varbinary, ColumnName)");
DropColumn("dbo.TableName", "ColumnName");
RenameColumn("dbo.TableName", "ColumnNameTmp", "ColumnName")
```

And the reverse in the Down method, if desired. (the above is pseudocode, forgive any syntax errors)

Comment: I didn't get it.! What is the replacement for <Convert statement from ColumnName?

Comment: Convert(varbinary, ColumnName) most likely... depends on what you're doing with your existing data.

Comment: Any luck with the convert statement?

Comment: I figured out where this goes after I watched this video: https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/ef/migrations-existing-databases

Comment: @DanS Working Awesome

Comment: You can declare AddColumn this way : `AddColumn<byte[]>("ColumnNameTmp", "dbo.TableName");`

Answer (score 4):

It can not change to column data type, Just try to delete or comment the column from your model add migration and update database, and in the second step add the column with byte[] data type and add migration igen. unfortunately if you hade any data in that column you will lose them.

```
    public class ExampleModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

comment the column and add migration and update database

```
    public class ExampleModel
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   //public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

and then add the column with byte[] data type

```
    public class ExampleModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Byte[] Code { get; set; }
}
```

and now add migration and then update database.

Comment: Quick and simple. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

alter TABLE [dbo].[ETABLISSEMENT_SANTES] ADD [ETS_LOGO_TMP] varbinary NULL;
alter TABLE [dbo].[ETABLISSEMENT_SANTES] DROP COLUMN [ETS_LOGO];
EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[ETABLISSEMENT_SANTES].ETS_LOGO_TMP', 'ETS_LOGO';

Answer (score 0):

protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{migrationBuilder.DropColumn("Password", "Users");
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<byte[]>(
name: "Password",
table: "Users",
type: "varbinary(max)",
nullable: false
/* oldClrType: typeof(string),
oldType: "nvarchar(max)"*/
);
}
//Update-Database or dotnet ef database update